# Can I throw more than one cargo overboard during a single Traitor's turn?

Tags: mad-zeppelin

In Mad Zeppelin, during each turn, each player gets two chances to play a Traitor card and take actions with that Traitor. Each traitor searches for cargo and gold, then activates their ability and/or throws cargo overboard.

The exact phrasing for throwing cargo is just slightly vague, though:

> Throw Cargo overboard. If your current Traitor’s color has been rolled on the dice, show a Cargo card from your hand. You must then pay Gold to the Safe equal to the number of Gold coins on the card.This represents bribing the ever-present guards on the Nostria. After paying the guards, the Cargo card is “thrown overboard.” Keep it face-up in front of you.

**Does this mean only throwing one cargo overboard per Traitor played, or can a Traitor throw cargo overboard more than once per turn?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.** Per a post on Board Game Geek where game designer Oliver Pauwels [responded to concerns](http://boardgamegeek.com/thread/551923/rules-additions-from-the-designer) about the vagueness of the rule book:

> Can more than one cargo be thrown off in a single round?
>
> Yes, as long as you have enough gold to pay : )

Comment: Wow, that makes Sadine Rochat (throw Level 2 cargo overboard for free) brokenly powerful, and she was already great. But at least it rescues Henchman 111 (1-gold discount per cargo) from the Pile Of Not Nearly As Useful As Everyone Else.